# How do I put Smooch's chat UI within popover?

Tags: ios, swift3, smooch

I have a problem and that is i'm trying to put Smooch's chat UI but this is always displayed in fullscreen mode in iPhone 6s. Can someone help me?

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "popoverSegue" {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        let popoverViewController: SmoochViewController = segue.destination as! SmoochViewController
        //popoverViewController.newViewController = Smooch.newConversationViewController()
        popoverViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.popover
        popoverViewController.popoverPresentationController!.delegate = self
    }
}
```

This is how I'm trying to present SmoochViewController which displays the chat.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    // Adding some values to the user
    SKTUser.current()!.firstName = "Kevin" // User's first name
    SKTUser.current()!.lastName = "Bustillos Acurio" // User's lastname
    SKTUser.current()!.email = "kevinbustillos21@hotmail.com" // User's email
    SKTUser.current()!.signedUpAt = Date() // User's sign in date

    let conversation: SKTConversation = Smooch.conversation()!

    // Debugging messages (can be deleted)
    for message in conversation.messages! {
        print("MESSAGES \((message as! SKTMessage).text)")
    }

    let newViewController: UIViewController = Smooch.newConversationViewController()!

    // Display Smooch UI (it displays the UI, the messages, avatars, all...)
    Smooch.showConversation(from: newViewController)


    // Just for debugging
    print("USER ID \(SKTUser.current()!.userId)")
    print("SMOOCH ID \(SKTUser.current()!.smoochId)")
    print("CURRENT USER FIRST NAME: \(SKTUser.current()!.firstName)")
    print("CURRENT USER LASTNAME: \(SKTUser.current()!.lastName)")
    print("CURRENT USER EMAIL: \(SKTUser.current()!.email)")
    print("CURRENT USER DATE: \(SKTUser.current()!.signedUpAt)")
}
```

And this is how I'm trying to present the chat in a different UIViewController

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default display mode for popovers on iPhone is to take the full screen. If you want a true popover, you'll need to implement the `adaptivePresentationStyle(for:)` method and return `.none`

https://rbnsn.me/ios-8-popover-presentations

I was able to get the view controller to appear in a popover using this code

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    let newViewController: UIViewController = Smooch.newConversationViewController()!

    newViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
    newViewController.popoverPresentationController!.delegate = self
    newViewController.popoverPresentationController!.sourceView = self.view

    self.present(newViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func adaptivePresentationStyle(for controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
    return .none
}
```

However, the text input doesn't play very nicely with the keyboard when presented in this way, so it might be better to present it fullscreen after all